# Merger Clusters of Different Layers in Open Layer Module Drupal 7

Tags: google-maps, javascript

I am using Open Layer module in Drupal 7, right now i have multiple different layers and each layer shows cluster of pins if they are within range of some distance . What i want to do is to do this for all layers , for example if layer one has cluster of 2 pins and layer 2 has cluster of 2 pins , it should show cluster of 4 PINS .
Thanks